# How to calculate an computed average in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to calculate average of rows depending on the time stamps and group by field1. For example, I have a table with

```
Field1      Field2      TImeStamp
  X           X1    11/19/2012 12:21:32
  X           X2    11/19/2012 12:22:32
  X           X3    11/19/2012 12:24:32
  Y           Y1    11/19/2012 12:21:32
  Y           Y2    11/19/2012 12:22:32
  Y           Y3    11/19/2012 12:23:32
  Y           Y4    11/19/2012 12:24:32
```

I have this kind of table with timestamp being inserted with current time along with the other fields. Now I would like to compute average based on time stamp. For example, I would like to have average of the latest + average of the other during a particular duration. In above case I would like to have :

```
Fields   Averaged function
  X        (X3+(X1+X2)/2)/2
  Y        (Y4+(Y1+Y2+Y3)/3)/2
```

For above I have to compute average of (now + average(now-1 minutes to now-5 minutes)). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
select field1, if(avgf2 = 0,maxf2,(maxf2+avgf2)/2) avgfun
from (select m.field1 field1,
             max(if(timestamp = maxts, field2, null)) maxf2,
             coalesce(avg(if(timestamp = maxts, null, field2)),0) avgf2
      from mytable m
      join (select field1, max(timestamp) maxts
            from mytable
            where timestamp between date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute) and now()
            group by field1) mm
      using (field1)
      where timestamp between date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute) and now()
      group by field1) x
```

The key is that aggregate functions like MAX and AVG ignore NULL.

To only check a particular time range, insert `WHERE timestamp BETWEEN <begin> AND <end>` into both subqueries.

Comment: Thanks for posting me a solution Mr. Barmar. But I am not able to make it work. Is there any syntax error in the code. I just replaced the variables in the script you provided. Also I don't the situation for handling time duration which I mentioned in the question. Can you please explain me a little if possible.

Comment: What is mm in 8th line. Is it misspelt? I am trying to understand you code now

Comment: It's just an alias for the subquery, which is required by MySQL. It's not being used for anything in this query -- `maxts` could be referenced as `mm.maxts`, but it's not necesary because it's not ambiguous.

Comment: Your code is working but when I modified it adding where timestamp between now() and now()-5 minute after 'mytable m' and 'group by field1', it is throwing me syntax error. I am trying to find it. please Let me know if the syntax for now() is wrong.

Comment: WHERE clauses go after JOIN clauses and before GROUP BY clause. See updated answer.

Comment: Worked finally thats great. Thank you